# .Net standard 1.6 dynamic dispatch possible in c#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I am experimenting with targeting multiple frameworks with Visual Studio 2017s new .csproj format.

I have written a small C# console app:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object val = 1;
        PrintMe((dynamic)val);
        val = "test";
        PrintMe((dynamic)val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintMe(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"integer: {i}");
    }

    public static void PrintMe(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"string: {s}");
    }
}
```

It works fine when targeting .Net Core 1.1 - but if I try to multi-target .Net Standard 1.6 by changing the .csproj file to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputType>exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputTypeEx>exe</OutputTypeEx>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Then when compiling I get the error:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project DynamicDipsatch could not be loaded.
1>------ Build started: Project: DynamicDipsatch, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>DynamicDipsatch -> D:\dev\projects\bittercoder\NetCoreExperiments\DynamicDipsatch\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\DynamicDipsatch.dll
1>Class1.cs(10,4,10,25): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
1>Done building project "DynamicDipsatch.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Adding a nuget package reference to Microsoft.CSharp or System.Dynamic.Runtime e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Does not fix the issue either (As found in some similar questions for vs2015, or in this microsoft connection question -> https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630573/missing-compiler-required-member-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-csharpargumentinfo-create)

Is it possible to perform dynamic dispatch in this way when targeting .net standard 1.6, and if so how?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630573/missing-compiler-required-member-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-csharpargumentinfo-create

Comment: Did you ever consider the pattern matching instead of `dynamic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build the project for .net standard, add a package reference to the `Microsoft.CSharp` NuGet package:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also note that your project is executable only in debug mode.. Set `<OutputType>` inside your main property group, not the one conditioned for Debug (looks like the project system bug).

Also, .net standard projects aren't meant to be executed so having an `Exe` output type isn't really useful for `netstandard` projects.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my question but I did add a PackageReference to Microsoft.CSharp, but that did not remedy the inability to compile.  Though I had an .exe this time, I originally was building a library when I hit this issue.

Let me know if any further info would be helpful.

Comment: does a `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` on the console help? I created a small lib project to test it.. If it still doesn't work for you it would be great if you could share your example project.

Comment: In creating a new test example of this it worked this time - go figure!

I then revisited my previous attempts - compared configuration files, everything was the same.  a Dotnet restore / dontnet build did not resolve the problem either.

I then uninstalled and reinstalled the nuget package reference to Microsoft.CSharp and rebuilt and things started working again.

Thanks for the help Martin.

Comment: @Bittercoder, Perhaps it just my installation, but I have found Visual Studio 2017 to be a quite buggy with .NET Core development. I often find that I have weird errors. As soon as I close and reopen Visual Studio, many of them magically disappear. Again, it could just be an issue with my installation, but I think the best VS2017 / .NET Core 1.x advice comes from Roy on the "IT Crowd". "Have you tried turning it off an on again?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8. :)

Comment: Totally agree @anthony-gatlin - having the exact same (fairly frustrating) experience, in that it seems restarting Visual Studio 2017 (especailly after any project changes) is almost essential and having them apply correctly.

Comment: @Bittercoder, Yes! Restarting Visual Studio (and sometimes my machine) has just become part of my general development/build process. You would think that a twenty year old product would be extremely stable. (The first version was released in 1997.) Unfortunately, that is not the case. They continue to add great features but they don't seem to be that good at fixing the bugs from current and past releases. I would be perfect happy to see an entire release devoted to nothing but application stability.